# Sharepoint rest api how to get list within url

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm new to Sharepoint.

We created a page in Sharepoint, it contains 4 list items.

https://abc.sharepoint.com/teams/OneTeam/SitePages/Newsfeed-page.aspx

I tried to use

```
https://abc.sharepoint.com/teams/OneTeam/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?filter=PromotedState eq 2&$select=BannerImageUrl,Description,Title
```

But I got all the list with the Site Pages ( which is expected ).

My question is how can I get these 4 items only from the above page ( Newsfeed-page.aspx )?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch only news pages from site pages library?

Answer (score 0):

R.R.

It looks like you forgot the $ before the $filter query parameter.

Can you try this instead:

```
_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$filter=PromotedState eq 2&$select=BannerImageUrl,Description,Title
```

That should give you all published news post pages.